# Merge field in Lightning template that is being called from Flow email alert

Tags: visual-workflow, email-alert, lightning-email-template

I have a Classic email template that I call via an email alert in process builder.  Because I want a non-letterhead look and need HTML features, I converted the Classic email template to a Lightning email template.  This works fine if I don't have any merge fields in the template.  However, I want to have the contact's first name in the template.  I decided to call the alert via a Flow instead of Process Builder thinking this would help as I include the Contact's id in the Flow's email alert.  I get an error when the alert is called indicating that the merge field isn't available.  How can I include a Contact's merge field in a Lightning template that is called via an alert in a flow?

I have tried {{{Contact.FirstName}}} and {{{Recipient.FirstName}}}.  I get an error with either one.

Comment: I have the same problem. It's really indicative of Salesforce's "house of cards" infrastructure. They half-ass a LOT of their work, and they release things without testing them thoroughly. It is very frustrating. Having a field in a Lightning template that it can't find results in the flow breaking, which is ludicrous. It should just ignore those fields and send the email.

Answer (score 1):

Currently Merge Fields in Lightning Email template using flow will not work and this is one of the limitation of this product.

If you will use you will get an error as:

> We can't save this record because the “test lightning template” process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. insufficient access rights on cross-reference id Error ID: 12345678-12345 (12345678)insufficient access rights on cross-reference id Error ID: 12345678-12345 (12345678)

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at the ['Send Better Email' Flow extension.](https://unofficialsf.com/send-better-email-flow-action/) It submits flow data to Lightning Email Templates using the Send Email action instead of the older Email Alert.